# Using CakePHP, save extra field (id, value, amount) HABTM tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hello Everything is right?
My problem is the following:

I have 3 tables:

```
create table products (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(80) not null,
    mold varchar(80),
    amount int,
    value decimal(10,2),
    real_value decimal(10,2),
    created datetime,
    modified datetime,
    active boolean default 1
);

create table sales (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    customer_id int not null,
    method_payment_id int not null,
    portions smallint(4),
    entry decimal(10,2),
    subtotal decimal(10,2),
    total decimal(10,2),
    debtor decimal(10,2), 
    expiration_date datetime,
    created datetime,
    modified datetime,
    active boolean default 1
);

create table products_sales (
    product_id int not null,
    sale_id int not null,
    amount smallint(4),
    value decimal(10,2)
);
```

In **products_sales** (HABTM) I had to add two extra fields (**amount** and **value**), because the value of a product is unstable and the other is the quantity purchased by the customer.

When I put in add() page:

```
  echo $this->form->input('Product');
```

CakePHP renders a , until then I understand.
But my need is: the customer must choose the **product** and the **amount** of it, or even if it is, the **product value** is also **sent**, **not only** the id (anything, I create a page just to report the amount, after confirmation 'the sale').

Then: 
**1** - How do I save the ID and value of the product at the same time? 
**2** - I am using the tables / relationships the right way? 
**3** - what better way to do this?

*Sorry for my English.
I hope you understand.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than HABTM, I think you want to use "hasMany through", where you create a separate model for `products_sales`. Here's a description from the Cake manual:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

There's a more complete description in the Cake 1.3 manual:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model

Comment: I managed to solve the problem as follows: kept the HABTM relationship, and after selecting the products on the sales page, redirect the user to a page that fetches all the products related to that sale, then the user enters the amount of each. It was the most practical method I found, but still, is not the way I want.